# With DenCun, we have now EIP-1153. But how can I use the new feature in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

With DenCun, we have now EIP-1153. But how can I use the new feature in Solidity?
It seems there need to be extensions for the keyword `transient`.

Where can I find this patch for upgrade of Solidity?
or I can always use the feature by directly using the op codes with assembly?

Answer (score 1):

> Solidity 0.8.24 supports the opcodes included in the upcoming Cancun
> hardfork and, in particular, the transient storage opcodes TSTORE and
> TLOAD as per EIP-1153.

---

> Users should note that the compiler does not yet allow using transient
> as a data location in high-level Solidity code. For the time being,
> data stored in this location can only be accessed using the TSTORE and
> TLOAD opcodes in inline assembly.

---

*(https://soliditylang.org/blog/2024/01/26/transient-storage/)*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Generosity {
    mapping(address => bool) sentGifts;

    modifier nonreentrant {
        assembly {
            if tload(0) { revert(0, 0) }
            tstore(0, 1)
        }
        _;
        // Unlocks the guard, making the pattern composable.
        // After the function exits, it can be called again, even in the same transaction.
        assembly {
            tstore(0, 0)
        }
    }
    function claimGift() nonreentrant public {
        require(address(this).balance >= 1 ether);
        require(!sentGifts[msg.sender]);
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: 1 ether}("");
        require(success);

        // In a reentrant function, doing this last would open up the vulnerability
        sentGifts[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```

Here's an example taken from the Solidity changelog docs, shown above.

- Solidity doesn't yet support the `transient` storage location **OPCODE** on the higher-level, the transpiler keyword hasn't been dedicated to that yet
- Though you can utilize the **assembly OPCODEs** to utilize it in your code already

And here's another example:

```
// This support was introduced with Solidity 0.8.24
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

contract TransientStoragePage {
    function tstore(uint location, uint value) public {
        assembly {
            tstore(location, value)
        }
    }

    function tload(uint location) public returns (uint value) {
        assembly {
            value := tload(location)
        }
    }
```